# Excel Macros - Search for a string in one column and replace the value in the other one?

Tags: excel, search, rows, vba

Okey, so basically this is was i want to do.

I have big excel sheet with data. I have different signals and all of these have different values. So in in Column C i have the signal names and in Column F i have the default values.

So what i want to do is that for every single signal that ENDS with "Qf" (ie search in whole column c, row by row), i would like to change the default value in Column F, for that specific row, to a value given in one other sheet, in A1 for instance.

Would really appreciate your help!

Many thanks!

Comment: It would help your question if you could include sample "before" and "after" data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub QfReplace()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Cells.Find("*", [C1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        If Right(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3), 2) = "Qf" Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This assumes data is in Sheet1, default value is in Sheet2 cell A1, and Sheet1 has no header row.